# vba conditional formatting with standard deviations - run time error with incorrect StDev

Tags: vba, excel, format, conditional-formatting

I am trying to move some of my conditional formatting to VBA but apply it to ranges that may change every time I run the macro. I think I have defined my ranges, variables, formulas and formats correctly (never done vba format.conditions so syntax could be wrong there). When I run the code it stops on the line

```
With checkrange.FormatConditions _
.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, Formula1:="=R" & cfcll.Row & "C" & q & "+ " & devone & ")")
```

with run-time error 5, invalid procedure or call.

The full section of code is as follows:

```
Dim cflastrow As Long
Dim cfrange As Range
Dim cfcll As Range
Dim checkrange As Range
Dim q As Long
Dim devone As Long
Dim devtwo As Long
Dim devthree As Long
Dim devfour As Long



cflastrow = finwb.Sheets("strt_Dash_Final").Cells(Rows.Count, 52).End(xlUp).Row
Set cfrange = finwb.Sheets("Strt_Dash_Final").Range("AV6:AV" & cflastrow)

For Each cfcll In cfrange
    If cfcll.value <> "" Then
        For q = 4 To 38
            Set checkrange = finwb.Sheets("Strt_Dash_Final").Range(Cells((cfcll.Row + 1), q), Cells((cfcll.Row + (cfcll.value - 2)), q))
            devone = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_P(checkrange)
                With checkrange.FormatConditions _
                    .Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, Formula1:="=R" & cfcll.Row & "C" & q & "+ " & devone & ")")
                    With .Font
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
                    End With
                    With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 255
                    End With
                End With
                With checkrange.FormatConditions _
                    .Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, "=" & Cells(cfcll.Row, q).value & "+ 2*stddev(" & checkrange & ")")
                    With .Font
                    .Color = 255
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
                    End With
                    With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 49407
                    End With
                End With
                With checkrange.FormatConditions _
                    .Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, "=" & Cells(cfcll.Row, q).value & "- stddev(" & checkrange & ")")
                    With .Font
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
                    .TintAndShade = -0.499984741
                    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
                    End With
                    With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
                    End With
                End With
                With checkrange.FormatConditions _
                    .Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, "=" & Cells(cfcll.Row, q).value & "- 2*stddev(" & checkrange & ")")
                    With .Font
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
                    End With
                    With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 5287936
                    End With
                End With
        Next q
    ElseIf cfcll.value = "" Then
        'nada
    End If
Next cfcll
```

Also, despite the range 'checkrange' definitely being correct (checked buy using checkrange = 5 and all values went to 5) devone always comes out as '1' when it should be something like 1.23.....

My theory is that I may not be using R1C1 correctly in the formula context but I saw it used this way in a couple of other examples so am now really not sure. Any help, as always, is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
With checkrange.FormatConditions _
.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, Formula1:="=R" & cfcll.Row & "C" & q & "+ " & devone & ")")
```

the formula will be `=R5C4+ 1)` if `cfcll.Row` is 5 and `q` is 4 and `devone` is 1.

As you see there is a closing parenthesis to much.

```
With checkrange.FormatConditions _
.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, Formula1:="=R" & cfcll.Row & "C" & q & "+ " & devone)
```

How to debug? Put the formula in a string variable first

```
sFormula = "=R" & cfcll.Row & "C" & q & "+ " & devone & ")"
```

then you would have seen this.

For users having non English Excel versions:
The formulas set for `FormatConditions` with VBA must be in the language of the Excel. They must not be in US-English as usual in VBA. So `R1C1` will be `Z1S1` in German Excel for example. Thats weird and annoying.

And to your `devone`: It is `Dim`ed as `Long` which is a integer type. So not a wonder that it does not contains `Double` values.

Comment: Ah, danke Axel!! Completely forgot Long is integers only. Also, I appreciate the tips on future debugging :D